# Java - placing items in JPanel like in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I try to do simple game, made of few 'screens' (menu, options, etc), which could work by displaying and hiding several JPanels. When I add some stuff on each panel and run the program, the only thing that appears is empty JFrame. I've made id looking like this:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("halo");
JButton button = new Button();
int WIDTH=600,HEIGHT=600;

public Frame(){

frame.add(game);
frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.add(panel1);
panel1.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT)
panel1.add(button);
button.setBounds(10,10,30,30);
}}
```

Everything essential is imported and declared, it's just 'simpled' version. What's wrong with it?

Comment: What is `game` in `frame.add(game)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a layout manager and *packing* after adding elements should fix the issue. Also it's unclear why you're referring to `frame` when you're constructing `this`. Try this version:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new Button();
    int WIDTH=600,HEIGHT=600;

    public Frame(){
    setTitle("Halo");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel1.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    button.setBounds(10,10,30,30);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

- Using the classname Frame may conflict with java.awt.Frame.
- You have to set the frame visible by calling `frame.setVisible(true);`  Before that, call `frame.pack();`
- You are subclassing JFrame, but also declaring and preparing a different JFrame.  Eliminate one of them.
- Add the components to the content pane of the JFrame:  frame.getContentPane().add(subcomponent);

Comment: The last point is mute since as of Java 1.5, JFrame#add delegates to the content pane

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, this means that only one component can occupy each of the five available positions that `BorderLayout` managers.

By default, if you don't specify where you want the component to be, it will be added to the `CENTRE` position

You should break your UI down into logical units and use `JPanel`s to manage them

You can use a combination of panels and layouts to generate complex UIs

You should also consider using a `CardLayout` to allow you to switch between base views

You should also call setVisible on the `JFrame` last, after you've established the basic UI, otherwise you'll need to call `revalidate` and and `repaint` to update the UI

You should avoid using `setBounds`/`setSize`/`setLocation` on components and rely on the use of layout managers, as they are designed to manage the differences in rendering pipelines that occurs across multiple different operating systems and hardware platforms